# Are leeches still used in modern medicine (for skin-grafts, finger-grafts, etc.)?

Tags: fingers, ancient-medicine, blood-letting-leeches

I know in antiquity that leeches were commonly used in medicine for any and everything in a technique known as "blood-letting." But I've heard recently that leeches have a anticoagulant and blood-thinning property that make it great for skin-grafts and reattaching digits, such as fingers or toes. Is this true?